# How to List Objects between two specific folders in S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want to know if it is possible to list objects between two specific folders.

```
$objects = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    "Bucket" => $bucket,
    "Prefix" => "2016/09/23"
));
```

The above code, will list me objects of that particular folder. But what i need is, if there is a way to list the objects between two folders. i.e., 2016/09/23 to 2017/1/14. I want list of objects between these two folders. is it possible??

Comment: You could just bring back a list of *all objects* and do the date checking within your own code. That would be faster since it would have fewer API calls (depending on how many files you have).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if Amazon provides this I suspect it doesn't, so one solution would be to loop through all dates:

```
$start_date = '2016/09/23';
$end_date = '2017/1/14';
$all_objs = array();

$date = $start_date;

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $date = date ("Y/m/d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    $ret_objs = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
                                              "Bucket" => $bucket,
                                              "Prefix" => $date,
                                        ));

    foreach ($ret_objs as $obj) {
         array_push($all_objs, $obj);
    }
}
```

I don't have an S3 instance to test but you could check and tweak it on your side.

Also make sure to set the timezone `date_default_timezone_set();` before building the dates.

Comment: `while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) { ...` looks a bit like an endless loop to me.